# PHP $get_ empty when data is posted from website, but not manual url

Tags: php, http, nginx, get

I have an odd problem with this script. I can post directly to it using the URL: "http://example.com/script.php?payer_email=foo&txn_id=9229fjfua822". But trying to post the same data from lets say http://requestmaker.com nothing is showing in the variable(s). I'm using nginx with PHP5.

```
<?php

$panel_url = 'http://example.com:23462/';

$username = $_GET['payer_email'];
$invoice = $_GET['txn_id'];
$trimmedinvoice = substr($invoice, -6);
$password = $trimmedinvoice;
$max_connections = 1;
$reseller = 0;
$bouquet_ids = array(
    1,
    2,
    3 );

$expirationdays = $_GET['custom'];
$expiration = "+$expirationdays day";
$expiredate = strtotime($expiration);

###############################################################################
$post_data = array( 'user_data' => array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'max_connections' => $max_connections,
        'is_restreamer' => $reseller,
        'exp_date' => $expiredate,
        'bouquet' => json_encode( $bouquet_ids ) ) );

$opts = array( 'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query( $post_data ) ) );

$context = stream_context_create( $opts );
$api_result = json_decode( file_get_contents( $panel_url . "api.php?action=user&sub=create", false, $context ) );

Echo "<b>Username:</b> <br>";
echo $username;

echo "<br></br>";
echo "<b>Password:<br></b>";
echo $password;

echo "<br></br>";
echo "<b>Expires (in unix time):<br></b>";
echo $expiredate;

?>
```

Been testing all night and found that adding this code will return the data being passed without problems. So the problem seems to be with the script, not the setup itself. Just can't figure where I'm going wrong.

```
print "CONTENT_TYPE: " . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] . "<BR />";
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
print "DATA: <pre>";
var_dump($data);
var_dump($_POST);
print "</pre>";
```

Output from the last block of code posting directly with the URL:

```
CONTENT_TYPE: 
DATA:
string(0) ""
array(0) {
}
```

Output from the last block of code posting using an external poster like the requestmaker:

```
CONTENT_TYPE:
text/html<BR />
DATA: <pre>string(35) "payer_email=foo&txn_id=9229fjfua822"
array(0) {
}
```

Comment: what's the output of the last block of code in your question?

Comment: Using an external website's post: CONTENT_TYPE: text/html<BR />DATA: <pre>string(35) "payer_email=foo&txn_id=9229fjfua822"
array(0) {
}     Going directly to the URL: CONTENT_TYPE: 
DATA:
string(0) ""
array(0) {
}

Comment: Even though the data is sent correctly stated in the last block of code it does not show up in my echo, nor is it sent to the API/ panel correctly. Only correctly when post is made directly to the URL.

Comment: while in your code you use $_GET, in your "debugging" block code you use $_POST. Am I missing something?

Comment: Dang it. My bad! Now I see why there was no output in the file. As Richard Smith pointed out below, I should use $_REQUEST to get both POST and GET data. Thank you for pointing this out for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST variables are in `$_POST` not `$_GET` (the latter contains the arguments appended to the URI).

You could use `$_REQUEST` which contains both POST and GET variables.

See [this document](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) for more.

Comment: Changed all the occurrences of $_GET with $_REQUEST and the script works like a charm! Great to have more than two eyes sometimes when you bet blinded by the problem. I was sure the problem was on the server after reading thru all my code without finding any problems. Thank you a lot!